# Is there an ASP.NET/HTML5 control for editing XML with intellisense?

Tags: xml, html, xsd

I wonder if there is a control that allows you to edit XML right in the browser. ideally, I need a control that allows our non-techie consultants to edit XML, that is validated against an XSD schema. Intelisense is a must. So far we are using a plain multiline textbox that is just terrible. We are looking for a better solution. Can someone help me with some advice, please?

Comment: Does it need to be embedded in a browser? You know you can easily do this with visual studio?

Comment: absolutely. We've got certain custom functionality that requires manual XML editing in the browser. All we need - some intelisense while editing XML. Does anyone know if Sky drive or TFS 2013 can provide this kind of functionality, please?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have a form version of the xml? Then the user just needs to fill out the form values and then you can use javascript or whatever to populate the xml?

Comment: Yep, that's true. Having form that forms the XML is just a workaround. The thing is we already have this XML edited by consultants. We just want it to have basic intelisense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out CodeMirror: http://codemirror.net/demo/xmlcomplete.html. This is probably the closest thing to your needs as it's an open source javascript library.

Also Wikipedia has a comparison of javascript based code editors:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors

Comment: yes, I saw it. It's pretty cool. The only problem is that this thing does not work with XSD. but, maybe, we can use javascript schema instead, like they propose.